# Add a background shape to a ImageView in xml Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview, shapes

The problem is that i can't put a shape behind my ImageView (that is a animation). The center of the ImageView have to be center-align with te shape.

The shape size is 92dp and from my animation es 48dp, so the shape have to include the animation.

This is the video when you can see what I try to get:
[Click Me](http://sendvid.com/71p1vart)

**This is my layout now:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView111"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**My shape is this:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="@color/primary" />

        <size
            android:height="92dp"
            android:width="92dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >

        <size
            android:height="92dp"
            android:width="92dp" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Some kind of solution for this? I spend lots of time to solved it and i couldn't :(

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: provide your Imageview background and it will be done
` android:background="@drawable/your_created_drawablefile_name" `

Comment: No, it is not working, the shape is gone. I can't see the shape, just the ImageView with the animation

Answer (score 0):

Dear I hope this helpful for you .

You can do this like:

First create you layout like this

**your layout**

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/scl"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView111"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="center"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@drawable/animationview_list"

android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**shape_oval.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

<gradient android:startColor="#E4E4E4"
  android:endColor="#E4E4E4"
  android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

**animationview_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="30" />

</animation-list>
```

Animation should not large to 48*48 otherwise not look good.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the I try it but the animation is not center with the oval, and the oval is not center with the device (horizontal and vertical)